# asp.net web application (.net framework) unable to call daatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.8

I am wanting to pass extra information to the sql sever only when someone creates an account successfully the problem is that I cant call the tableadapter that has my query on it. I have the dataset xsd made and the tables made but I cant seem to call to them this is done all being done in a asp.net web application (.net framework)

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using CAEWEBBASE.Models;

namespace CAEWEBBASE.Account
{
    public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                <want to add call to table adapter here to pass data>
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                //string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                //string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                //manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use EntityFramework or Another ORM?

Comment: i could try though it would suck to have to start all over the login page is off of the template but i have a whole other section that ive built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. First, I had the dataset in the `App_Data` folder; it needs to be in the `App_Code` folder for it to function as a proper dataset with tables inside.

Next, you have to open the dropdown on the dataset, then select the designer, then change the build action to compile, then rebuild your project, and then you will be able to access any debatable in your code behind.